# Hide Billing Agreement in Order Summary Section of Paypal Login Page using Set Express Checkout

Tags: paypal

Can we hide the billing agreement for recurring payment in order summary of paypal login page using SetExpressCheckout?

Any help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To put it bluntly: collecting the keys to bill a PayPal account without letting the accountholder know is pretty shady territory. Don't go there.

You may believe you are telling the user clearly elsewhere in the flow, but PayPal can't be certain that is the case for every merchant, reliably, today and in the future, so they have some minimal notification requirements to protect their account holders. You the merchant cannot suppress these notifications if you are requesting this level of access to their wallets, and that's a Good Thing (tm).

PayPal's language on the login page re: billing agreements has evolved over the years, generally from more intrusive to less intrusive/higher conversion, but I don't believe they are or ever will be entirely suppressed in general or under the control of a particular merchant.

Comment: Actually, the problem is that I need to be able to checkout recurrent as well as non-recurrent payment through setexpress for which I have to set it as recurrent. And by doing that I have to supply billing agreement for non-recurrent as well which is where I need the solution on. Are there any other alternatives to be able to checkout in one single checkout for recurrent and non-recurrent payments?

Comment: Not sure I understand. In SetEC you tell PayPal what you are directing people over to do. Can't you give SetEC different parameters depending upon whether you are requesting recurring payments or not in each case? If you don't decide/determine until later, yeah you are in a tough spot. Consider if you can modify/reorder the flow. Or you can send a user through a second time (ugly) if you need to ask for billing agreement approval later. Some merchants doing both always ask for a billing agreement and put the initial cart through as the first item on the agreement but that is not ideal either.